# Named pipes: Getting a crash on ReadFile

Tags: c#, vb6, named-pipes

I am writing a program in which VB6 (server) will communicate with C# (client) using named pipes. The server part crashes on a call to `ReadFile`.

Server code (VB6):

```vb
Dim strIn As String
Dim hPipe As Long
openMode = PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX Or FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH
pipeMode = PIPE_WAIT Or PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE
hPipe = CreateNamedPipe(pipeName, openMode, pipeMode, 100, 20000, 20000, 50000, sa)
res = ConnectNamedPipe(hPipe, ByVal 0)
cbnCount =10
res = ReadFile(hPipe, strIn, 10, cbnCount, 0)  ' --> VB6 crashes here
```

Client code (C#):

```cs
NamedPipeClientStream pipeClient = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", pipeName, PipeDirection.InOut);
pipeClient.Connect();
byte[] arr = new byte[100];
string str = "My name is XYZ";
arr = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str);
pipeClient.Write(arr, 0, arr.Length);
pipeClient.Flush()  
pipeClient.WaitForPipeDrain();
```

`ReadFile` delaration is:

```vb
Declare Function ReadFile Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hFile As Integer, ByRef lpBuffer As String, _
  ByVal nNumberOfBytesToRead As Long, ByRef lpNumberOfBytesRead As Long, _
  ByVal lpOverlapped As Long _
) As Integer
```

Comment: You never declare `string`s `ByRef` in VB6's `Declare` statement, unless you really know what you are doing. It must be `ByVal lpBuffer As String`. You also must initialize `strIn` before the call. `hFile` must be `Long`, and the return value is also `Long`.

Comment: ReadFile should return a long. By "crash" do you mean you you can't examine the ReadFile result, or Err.LastDllError?

Comment: Is it 32 or 64 bit o/s?

Comment: @GSerg Thanks ! Your solution worked.